# FQL Friend's Events Query

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-fql

I know there is similar questions like this, but I couldn't find anything as specific as my question is.

I'm trying to experiment with the Graph API Explorer, using FQL Queries. Before I put this into a script, I want to be able to use the Graph API Explorer (the FQL Queries window), to generate a list of all events that are being attended by any of my friends.

I saw an old post similar to this, but wasn't able to get it to work. 
Here is what I have, not sure where to go from here:

```
SELECT name, location, start_time, end_time, eid FROM event 
WHERE eid IN (
   SELECT eid FROM event_member 
   WHERE (uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())  OR uid = me())
   )
   AND start_time > now()
```

Comment: FQL have been deprecated and will be totally removed in just a few months.

Comment: I'd still like to know how to do this, though.

Comment: You can't. The API doesn't let you see friends events if they don't grant permission to your app